# Qt Chart mouse over event

Tags: qt, qtcharts

I have a chartView with a few different QScatterSeries and QLineSeries.

I would like to implement an event that is thrown if one moves with the mouse over one of the scatter points to display some additional information about this point.

I'm not sure where I should start to implement this. Should this event be part of my QChartView, my QChart or is it possible to stick it to my QScatterSeries?

Answer (score 0):

[hovered](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxyseries.html#hovered) might be what you want.

`QXYSeries` provide [hovered](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxyseries.html#hovered) signal, both `QScatterSeries` and `QLineSeries` are inheritance from `QXYSeries`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event inherited from `QXYSeries`, hovered. It is an event for series no for QChart or QChartView like:

```
connect(my_serie, &QLineSeries::hovered, this, &ChartView::myFunction);
```